# Reference request for the definition of logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, definitions

I am looking for philosophical texts on the question of what the definition of logic is or should be. I am pretty sure many logicians and philosophers have written about that philosophical topic. I would like to see some mathematical and philosophical references.

Comment: Like always, a good start is the encyclopedia entry https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Intr
From its introduction „Philosophically, logic is at least closely related to the study of correct reasoning.” I consider this sentence a good guide. And for the first approximation I would even cancel the words “at least closed related to”. Hence the short answer: "Logic is the study of correct reaosoning."

Comment: @JoWehler Great now all you need is a definition of "correct reasoning" and you're all done!

Comment: (Yeah, yeah, reasoning for which the truth of the premises implies the truth of the conclusion. Now tell me precisely what you mean by logical truth, and *then* you're done. While you're at it, is the axiom of choice true or false, and how could you tell?)

Comment: Saying logic is the study of correct reasoning is like saying linguistics is the study of correct grammar.

Comment: @causative Great remark, you got my point :-) Guided by the view that logic is correct reasoning one can now investigate what are correct and what are wrong syllogisms. One finds as a minimal requirement that a correct syllogism is truth-conserving: True premises provide a true conclusion. From the entry point of Aristotelian syllogisms one can move on to modern logic in the form of different mathematical calculi.

Comment: @JoWehler Like I said, if that is your answer you would need to define precisely what you mean by logical truth. Truth is what we get from correct logic, and correct logic is what gives us truth. Defining one in terms of the other doesn't tell us what either is.

Comment: @causative Please note the OP's question is a reference request. - You ask for more, this could be a separate question.

Comment: @JoWehler It's more well-founded to say that logic is the study of formal systems of derivation. We need not bring truth into it. Any system where we have formal rules for when we can derive a new string of symbols based on a previous set of strings of symbols, is logic.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I think you’re conflating *Logos* and *Logic* https://human.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Composition/Specialized_Composition/Bad_Ideas_About_Writing_(Ball_and_Loewe)/04%3A_Bad_Ideas_About_Writing_Techniques/4.03%3A_Logos_is_Synonymous_with_Logic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word 'logic' is used in different senses depending on context, and arguably it has shifted in meaning over time. Historically, logic is concerned with rational belief and inference. It is the study of what distinguishes a good argument from a bad argument. As such, it is closely related to how people think and how people ought to think. Hence it was considered to have a normative element to it: you ought to reason correctly and you ought to avoid fallacies.

Sometimes the sense is even broader and 'logical' becomes almost a synonym for 'rational'. We may have Mr Spock to blame for this. According to him it is illogical to cause the death of a species of whale. What exactly that has to do with correct reasoning and argument is not clear, but it is a common usage.

As our understanding of logic and reasoning progressed, it was natural to express it using formal rules. Aristotle, the stoic philosophers, the medieval logicians, Leibniz, Boole and many others made advances in this direction. As late as the mid-19th century, logic was still viewed as being mainly about how people reason. Fundamental principles of logic were called "laws of thought".

A significant break came with Frege at the end of the 19th century. Frege and his contemporaries advanced the idea that logic is not fundamentally about reasoning but about the relationships of logical consequence between propositions. Logic is the study of what follows from what. Logic describes and catalogs these relationships but it is not normative.

Frege's approach proved very fruitful. As the 20th century progressed, it resulted in powerful formal systems of logic. It allowed us to formulate axiom systems for arithmetic and other branches of mathematics. It led to the development of proof theory and model theory. It led to a formal understanding of computation. As a result, 'logic' is often used today in a much more narrow way to refer to the study of these formal systems.

That said, logic is not just the concern of mathematicians and computer scientists. Linguists, cognitive psychologists and AI researchers have a stake in contributing to our understanding of logic. Some philosophers pursue research in logic and continue to extend its boundaries.

The upshot is that there is no simple definition of logic. Logicians themselves disagree over exactly what counts as logic and where the boundaries are between logic and non-logic. Some regard formal logic as an attempt to create an ideal language. Others as a way to improve and regiment our existing natural languages. Others see logic as an abstract formal model of language.

There are many books on the philosophy of logic that cover this and other questions. Some are:

- Daniel Cohnitz and Luis Estrada-Gonzalez, *An Introduction to the Philosophy of Logic*.
- Susan Haack, *Philosophy of Logics*.
- Graham Priest. *Doubt Truth to be a Liar*.
- W.V. Quine, *Philosophy of Logic*.
- Ian Rumfitt, *Boundary Stones of Thought*.

Comment: Is there a better word? Aristotle's teachings on logic are contained in the *Organon* and he describes good arguments and bad arguments (the latter in the Sophistical Refutations). Aristotle taught these things, so they were there to be studied. Why write about them if the intention is not for people to study them? If you find the word 'study' odd, I suppose one could say instead that logic is concerned with what distinguishes a good argument from a bad argument.

Comment: If logic was the study of correct reasoning, we wouldn't say that arguments may be logical or illogical. 2. "*so they were there to be studied*" Of course. The discipline is called "formal logic". 3. "*logic is concerned with*" No. Formal logic is concerned with. Logic is what decides whether an argument is logical or illogical. If logic was the study of arguments, nobody would care what the definition of logic is. Do you know of anyone asking what the definition of chemistry is?

Comment: @Speakpigeon the world decides whether an argument of ours exactly or otherwise captures enough of a correspondence with reality so as to be a good argument.

Comment: @Bumble Could you maybe provide some additional references discussing the _"philosophy of logic"_, particularly with respect to substructural logics, and even more particularly linear logic and its resource-awareness? Like Girard points out as a trivial example, classical/standard logic (without resource awareness) fails to model vending machine behavior. So it's obvious that classical logic's rules of inference aren't "universal", in particular, A==>B.&.A==>C **=/=>** A==>B&C for the vending machine. But I'm not seeing the "philosophical" implications of this for myself. Thanks.

Comment: @PW_246 "*the world decides whether an argument of ours exactly or otherwise captures enough of a correspondence with reality so as to be a good argument.*" The brain does, not the world.

Comment: @eigengrau "*classical logic's rules of inference aren't "universal", in particular, A==>B.&.A==>C =/=> A==>B&C for the vending machine.*" Could you give me some references for this?

Comment: @Speakpigeon see the first two pages of  https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=c65de72f7f4e38992bf1e78677d7840604de9beb

Comment: @Speakpigeon (1) I wouldn't say arguments are logical or illogical. Arguments may be valid, sound, cogent, strong. Or their opposites. (2) Logic traditionally is concerned with what distinguishes a good argument from a bad argument. Not just formal logic. Many fallacies are informal and these are part of what makes an argument bad. (3) I see no reason why someone would not care about the definition of logic in the broad traditional sense. (4) I see no reason why it does not make sense to ask the definition of chemistry. It is the study of the interactions between atoms, molecules and ions.

Comment: @eigengrau Beall and Restall's, *Logical Pluralism* is a sympathetic account of alternatives to classical logic, though not specifically linear logic. Priest's *Doubt Truth to be a Liar* includes Priest's defence of dialetheism. Susan Haack's *Philosophy of Logics* is sympathetic to pluralism, hence the 'logics' in the title, though it does not cover linear logic specifically. There are still a few people defending logical monism, including Erik Stei *Logical Pluralism and Logical Consequence* and Griffiths and Paseau *One True Logic*.

Comment: @Bumble Thanks for the additional reference. Downloaded a copy of Beall and Restall, but haven't had much of an opportunity to look at it yet. Not quite sure that _"In this book we present and defend what we call logical pluralism, the view that there is more than one genuine deductive consequence relation,..."_ is exactly what I'm looking for, but will look through it a bit more carefully.

Answer (score 4):

According to Aristote, *Prior An.*, 24a10-24a15: "First we must state the subject of the enquiry and what it is about: the subject is *demonstration* (ἀπόδειξιν), and it is about demonstrative understanding. Next we must determine what a *proposition* is, what a term is, and what a *deduction* (συλλογισμός)."

Here we have already the basic "objects" to be enquired by *logic*: proof, deduction, language.

"Traditionally, (formal) logic is concerned with the analysis of sentences or of propositions and of proof with attention to the *form* in abstraction from the *matter*" (Alonzo Church, 1956).

Logic is *formal*: "The discovery of the formal treatment of logic, i.e. of the possibility of describing deductive reasoning with sentences in terms of their form, appears with Aristotle" (S.C. Kleene, 1952).

Modern logic is *mathematical*: "The subject of formal logic when treated by the method of setting up a formalized language is called symbolic logic, or mathematical logic" (Alonzo Church, 1956).

And see Jean-Yves Beziau, *Why Logics* (2023): "The substantive 'logic' is used in three different ways:
(1) reasoning;
(2) a system describing reasoning, that is, 'a logic';
(3) the science studying reasoning through the development of logical [*I would say*: symbolic] systems and tools [*I would add*: mathematical] to study them."

Answer (score 1):

A book that explains what Logic is is **P.F. Strawson, *Introduction to Logical Theory***.  The first chapter is devoted to the problem of what Logic and doing Logic is; then there are several chapters presenting various kinds of formal logics and their properties; finally two chapters devoted to the problem of inductive reasoning, what that is and how it essentially differs from probabilistic reasoning (which rather happens to be a mode of deduction).

Strawson, broadly speaking (and for what it's worth), belongs to the Analytic/(post-)Wittgesteinian tradition: the emphasis is on Logic proper (whence the capital 'L'), i.e. the logic of/in natural language, then how and to which extent that has any relation with formal logic.