What philosophers have to say as to what logic is and why it exists?
In my view, logic is just a native cognitive capacity which provides a selective advantage to the organism which has it. This seems a very reasonable theory. I have been unable to find much in way of reasonable alternatives to it. I am not even sure that there is any.
So my question is:

What are the main theories proposed by philosophers as to what logic is, and why it exists?

Thank you for any scholarly reference.

See here: https://seop.illc.uva.nl/entries/logic-ontology/, specifically section 2.1. Logic has to do with a competitive advantage, but our minds are not only logical. We make mistakes all the time. Hence, we need formal systems to test out our reasoning and to hold ourselves accountable, given the principles we hold as true.

I think the objection one might take is. WHY does logic give a competitive advantage? It seems like it must be that logic accurately represents something in/about the world outside the organism who is able to do logic. e.g. When I do multiplication, I get the right answer. If I do a silly dance and then roll a dice, I don't always get the right answer. So somehow the universe is ordered according to logic and not according to silly-dance-dice-rolling?

Sometimes we take logic for granted, but I think yours is a good question--to step back and ask how it is even possible that we can think logically in the first place, and how it is that logic correlates so well with the real world. Most Christian philosophers answer by saying that logic is an expression of God's rational mind; i.e., not above God, and not created by God, but part of His very nature. Since we are created in God's image, our own capacity for rationality is like a limited "mirror-image," in a sense, of God's capacity for reason. Further, since God built the world using thi

Maybe logic is not a faculty but a linguistic/social construct.

Looks like a duplicate of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108605/reference-request-for-the-definition-of-logic

The dominant view is still the anti-psychologism of Frege-Husserl - logic is an objective entity:"Frege’s main thesis is that mathematics and logic are not part of psychology, and that the objects and laws of mathematics and psychology are not defined, illuminated, proven true, or explained by psychological observations and results." There are recent criticisms of this orthodoxy, but even critics more commonly take logic to be empirical law, not just evolved capacity.

Sounds like this is about 'reason' rather than 'logic', particularly as "a native cognitive capacity", e.g. "logic is more specific and focuses on the form and validity of arguments, while reason is a broader concept that involves the mental processes of thinking, understanding, and forming logical judgments." c/o Redbcm.com. And so I would suggest having a read of Heidegger's The Principle of Reason (originally published in German in 1955-56).

This question is similar to: Reference request for the definition of logic. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
